# Why std::string doesn't have methods for upper/lower case, format etc?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl

Why `std::string` is not smart at all. Why it doesn't have **string manipulation** features like `Format/sprintf`, convert to upper, convert to lower, take input from integer/real, to convert to integer/real, and other important functions any string class should have (Reference: `CString`, `wxString`, `System.String`, BASIC strings...).

I am aware that there are new functions like `std::to_string`, but.. why `string` itself is so dumb. Why it is just `vector<char>`? Why still in stone age? Why *standards* don't make it smart!?

Comment: _That's the way they roll_

Comment: To increase traffic to stackoverflow.com with questions about how to manipulate strings in C++. It's a conspiracy.

Comment: Not justified, just like string class!

Comment: Unlike System.String in C# etc., std::string does not require a specific charset. Many things are not possible without.

Comment: Take it that you've never had to fight against or work around smart classes.  Formatting is very localized - it doesn't belong to the string class.  Dumb is easiest to use.  Does exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Can we not forget charset? A text manipulation class should have important features.

Comment: And let's not forget that quite a few C++ programmers call std::string bloated as it is!

Comment: @niel, no conspiracy. I am really fed up with this idiot class. I love STL

Comment: The `string` class was designed with a single goal in mind -- to manage sequences of characters, and do that well. The rest of the kitchen sink is left to the responsibility of the developer (possibly through other libraries).

Comment: *Can we not forget charset?* You have clearly no idea what you´re saying.

Comment: Okay. Lets call `std::wstring`. It supports, what then? Another dumb class

Comment: @Ajay: What´s with wstring? It does not require anything, too. As long there is this design decision, there can´t be case conversion etc.

Comment: @deviantfan, it also doesn't have common features of a string class!

Comment: Because [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: @Ajay Like what? Everything in the question above requires to understand characters (not like C++ char, but natural characters), not only bytes.

Comment: @ChrisDrew, Exactly! It should perform all responsibility. We need external functions to do many features it should have. C++ doesn't have extension methods either.

Comment: @deviantfan, That's what I am saying, it is string, not bytes - it must not behave (just) as vector of chars.

Comment: "A text manipulation class should have important features." `std::string` is not a text manipulation class. Text manipulation belongs outside the strings it manipulates. That other languages need to package everything inside a class is a flaw in those languages.

Comment: @Ajay *it must not behave (just) as vector of chars* . That´s your opinion, but the C++ comitee thinks different. That´s all. They don´t want to have a full ICU and hundred other things in the standard C++ runtime; but a easy-to-use generic thing with a broad use-case spectrum.

Comment: Different languages do things in different ways.  Unlike C#, C++ does not have extension methods.  You could join the C++ steering committee and suggest adding extension methods.  Extension methods are more trouble than they're worth - especially for program maintenance.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Disagree. Look at .NET `System.String`, Java `String`, old GWBASIC string type...

Comment: @cpu - Not favoring extension methods - just saying programmers cant even upgrade `std::string`

Comment: @Ajay Another point: These classes are far from complete. They can do more than std::string, but for real text handling (eg. Unicode normalization etc.etc.), you still need an external lib.

Comment: @deviantfan, Why external LIB? That's my point. Why `std` namespace doesn't have all features of text-handling? I am not asking astounding XML parser

Comment: @Ajay Why std:: don´t have full 3D model file format support? Special things for special applications, or the one-responsibility thing.

Comment: @deviantfan, I mean for extended text handling (like ToUpper in your opinion!), you need external LIB, why? Why other string classes have them? Why no one is saying C++ should have the features?!

Comment: @Ajay As I said before, your other classes are not perfect, and if you want a proof, i can give you examples. They can´t even properly detect if two strings are equal. No programming language I know has full built-in support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Case comparisons and conversions, in full generality, are hard and require too much information; it's as simple as that.

In American and British English it's simple indeed.

But what about German? E.g. the lower case ß (which in lower case is one character, but in upper case would be two characters: SS).

What about wide character sets which `std::string` can support? What about accented characters from other European languages like ë?

There's nothing idiotic about this class at all. It has a well defined specification and the standards committee will not emit functionality that could break the language.

As for formatting, this is largely deferred to the streaming libraries, e.g. `std::stringstream`. There's no reason to incorporate directly into `std::string`.

Comment: The biggest problem is actually, in Turkish the uppercase of `i` is `İ` not `I`.

Comment: @KennyTM: That's one of my favourites too. Mine is the German ß since that can cause reallocation of the string buffer!

Comment: We have `std::wstring` for that.

Comment: Everyone loves C++, I do. Everyone loves STL, I do too! Everyone has rated this answer, I won't! It doesn't justify. Why C++ people should be treated like third-world. We should demand it! :)

Comment: @Bathsheba: there is `std::string::push_back()` which also reallocates the string buffer.

Comment: @Ajay Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778165/why-stdstring-doesnt-have-methods-for-upper-lower-case-format-etc#comment42135461_26778165 before complaining further. And yes, I´m serious. They are *far* from perfect.

Comment: @KennyTM: Indeed, but don't you think that reallocation on case conversion would be one of the weirdest consequences of having such a method in `std::string`?

Comment: @ajay: Downvote my answer if you don't like it.

Comment: @ajay `string` does not mandate the language it is in.  Nor the format of its data.  utf-8 is an acceptable data format, whuch supports all these.  And `wstring` also has to deal with single words becoming two on case change.  All of thise other string classes are hacks, and they do make working with english ascii 7 bit clean text from the USA marginally easier.  But they make other optuons **harder** with implicit global state (is `1,1` two numbers or one?  Depends if you loaded the itunes plugin recently!)

Comment: @Yakk data-format, UTF, language has nothing to do with my concern. `std::string` is not a good String class - it is just a data holder, doesn't have many functions needed for text.

Comment: @Ajay how do you capitalize stuff without knowing what the bytes mean?  Should capitalize reallocate?  How do you convert from string to integer when you don't know if `.` or `,` is your separator, or what the bytes mean?  There is more than 1 unicode code point for `0`, do you support them all?  Is 1/10th in decimal represented as `0.1` or `0,1`?  Every single one of these classes you mentioned makes (sometimes extremely) questionable decisions or relies upon global state to answer these questions.  `wxString` for example stores only unicode characters.  And the docs say "avoid using it"!

Comment: Even the Wx docs say don't use wxstring: [While the use of wxString is unavoidable in wxWidgets program, you are encouraged to use the standard string classes std::string or std::wstring in your applications and convert them to and from wxString only when interacting with wxWidgets.](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html)!  When you implement something as complex as you want, you end up with legacy garbage and need to throw it out and replace it.  `std::string` sucks for many reasons: it failing to support type conversion and capitalization isn't one of them.

Comment: @Ajay Feel free to implement your own string class, show it to us, and answer following questions. Can it case-convert a ä in every common serialization (yes, there are many, even within UTF8)? Can it store/process any text an external source (haha, charset detection = impossible)? Can it understand japanese numbers? Does it know what´s used instead of am/pm at the Phillipines, and how to display a date to the Minguo calendar system? And is everything there not much harder to use than existing libs? Something answered with "no"? Then it´s bad. ... You really have absolutely no idea of this.

Comment: @deviantfan, Oh come on man! Why `std::string` has find and `substr` then? Does it handle all you mentioned? No. Then why you asking me to implement them? Why does it have `c_str()` method? If it has, it has to have upper/lower at least!

Comment: @Yakk, I must agree to you on that! But... question remain the same - why std::string is not rich, it should have been for C++ programmers?

Comment: @Ajay These functions work on *bytes*. The C++ comitee does not claim that they support any international thing. Finding byte patterns etc. is useful, even without any text. Again, the comitee does not want a full-feature string class. (And what´s with c_str? Usually a "return pointer", has nothing to do with this here).

Comment: (And if you look up the description of these functions, please read the basic definition section of the standard too)

Comment: @deviantfan. Why not C++ committee want a full fledged string class, when they can come up with std::mutex ? I believe string is more used construct than a mutex. Why we can't have a good string class?

Comment: @Ajay Are you trolling or just that thick-headed? **Text handling and internationalization is a very big and complicated topic and not trivial.** Even if you don´t believe it. And just because they don´t want such a large bloated feature-monster, that´s no reason to leave completely unrelated things out too. (And bye, because I´ve better use for my time)

Comment: @ajay `std::mutex` does what it does well.  It has one job, and does it efficiently.  `std::string` does what it does ... well, mediocrely (again, not a great class, but for unrelated reasons).  But it does its one job.  It is not a full featured text handling and internalization library, and does not pretend to be.  "Simple" problems like capitalization and convert to/from other formats are **not simple**.  `to_string` is even poor, but at least it isn't strongly coupled to the class (saying "method X is obsolete" is harder than "function Y is obsolete" in my experience)

Comment: (What a great coincidence, Jon Skeet´s most upvoted answer is about internationalization)